# ElasticSearch average aggregation in results

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get average price in top 10 sale products, so I do the following query:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "top_sale_avg_price": {
            "avg": {"field": "price"},
            "aggs": {
                "top_sale_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [{"buy_count": {"order": "desc"}}],
                        "size": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I get an error, it says `"AggregationInitializationException[Aggregator [top_sale_avg_price] of type [avg] cannot accept sub-aggregations]"`

Answer (score 0):

[Top hits](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) will find the ten documents that best match your query (i.e. score highest). The sort is then performed on this result set - so top hits won't work for you.

You also can't nest `top_hits` and `avg` inside each other - you can only nest inside a bucket (e.g. terms, histogram, range, etc.)

To meet your requirements, you could run 2 queries.
The first to find the matching documents (top ten sale products):

```
{
  "fields" : ["_id"],
  "sort": [
    { "buy_count": { "order": "desc" }}
   ],
  "size":10,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}'
```

The second query to get an average sale price - you'll need to populate the ids.

```
{
  "filter" : {
    "ids": {
        "values": [ "07cfbc09-360b-10d8-e053-28ab48a5c296", "07cf438e-7830-19ec-e053-28ab48a59c0b"]}
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "top_sale_avg_price" : {
      "avg": {"field" : "price" }  }
   }
}'
```